# One word to denote the category which falls under "everything except the best"

Tags: word-request

When comparing certain things do we have one word to denote the category which falls under "everything except the best"?

It can't be the worst because there are some which belong to just bad or not good and rest of them can be under worst category.

Edit: Scenario is some numbers or names are not as good as one of them. Hence I want to remove all the numbers or names that are not best except one.

Comment: It would help to know what kind of things we're talking about - we might use a different expression for people than we would for items or animals.

Comment: @ColleenV  Well we can compare some data like numbers w.r.t some criteria.

Comment: For data, we typically use [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) to describe values that fall below a certain value in a distribution. It's difficult to think of a word that is "not the best". Usually we talk about the best, and then mention "everything else" or "everything except the best". We generally don't make categories for "all things that are not this one thing". Usually the best is ["in a class of its own"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-a-class-of-its-own).

Answer (score 2):

It depends how **best** is defined.

In mathematics, given certain scenrios, all values that are not best may be referred to as

> **nonoptimal**

since there is only one optimal point

Within a school's graduating class, all except the top student, by certain criteria, are

> **non-valedictorians**

since the valedictorian is "the best" of the class

I think to find the **single word** descriptions you're looking for, you may need to find the term for **best** in that situation and prefix **non-**

Answer (score 2):

Consider [suboptimal](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/suboptimal):

> below the ​highest ​level or ​standard, or not done in the best way possible

Answer (score 1):

How about "The Rest"...?

"Mess with the best, die like the rest."

Comment: Depending on the context this may or may not make any sense.

Comment: @RonaldB what about while comparing numbers. Also I want one word.

Comment: @user30881 Sorry. I think you have to accept the 'The' article, since you were asking for "everything except **the best**". :) And I think that for numbers it still applies.